# Multiple PHP Scripts in Background Using Mysqli connection - speed gain possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm bootstrapping a simple script to multi-task in PHP. I'm using exec() to fire off 4 scripts using the > /dev/null & option to push them into the background.

```
exec('php importer_001.php > /dev/null &');

exec('php importer_002.php > /dev/null &');

exec('php importer_003.php > /dev/null &');

exec('php importer_004.php > /dev/null &');
```

Each script pulls sql files from a folder which are then loaded into temp databases and data harvested into a single archive table. Here's my question: I don't seem to see any performance gain here with the overall task being split into 4 chunks. Is the lack of speed gain a result of the mysqli protocol, or is the issue with spawning child processes? I used the article below as a reference, but keep the test super simple and did not bother to keep the script running and monitoring the PID's, etc. I just opened my PHPmyadmin database listing page and watched them load and dump till it stopped, to keep the test rather simple. BTW, I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04 with PHP 7.0, Mysql 5.7.

https://medium.com/async-php/multi-process-php-94a4e5a4be05#.uoscp0bji

Comment: Find out where your bottleneck is. CPU utilization, network bandwidth, the SQL server itself.. Voting to close this as too broad.

Comment: Are they all writing into the same table? If the table is locked by one of the inserts, that will block the others.

Comment: if you have 4 scripts hammering the db, then performance may/will be worse than one single script hammer. especially if the db's resource constrained and has to flush caches regularly to swap between the four jobs.

Comment: @Barmar - They all eventually write their culled data to one archive data... might be the issue!

Comment: @MarcB - I actually get about a 10 second boost as the code currently stands, nothing to brag about...

Comment: Use `show processlist` to see if there are a bunch of queries that are waiting.

Comment: I see the list, it's hard to gauge, but I did see 4 running queries at the same time, though sometimes I see sleeping. I also see 'system lock' when dropping temp db's - caught my eye.